# Grails one to many relationship behavior

Tags: grails

I know that one of the benefits of the one to many relationships is cascading behavior such as the deletion of a parent(owning) object resulting in
the deletion of the children(objects the parent owned) but what if the objects owned by it are also owned by another parent do they still get deleted if only one parent gets deleted?

Comment: Did you try it? I suspect you didn't because you would have found out that it doesn't delete the child instances if they are in use by another instance.

Comment: @Joshua Moore Although that is the behaviour I suspected, and wanted, no, I hadn't tried it. Thanks for confirming for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GORM/Grails is smart enough to figure out in this case that the child instances should not be deleted when they are in use by another instance. (As indicated in my comments to the original question)

Comment: I was wondering why you hadn't posted that comment as an answer so that I may mark you as correct. Thanks again.